# SQL Server 2008 Installation Incomplete

Tags: sql-server-2008

This question may look stupid and dumb but I needed to ask this. I installed SQL server 2008 but what I have finally installed is this (see the images).

Is SQL Server 2008 is installed? If not how can I install it?

**Start Menu**

[image]

**Control Panel (Add/Remove)**

[image]

Comment: Not programming related should really be on serverfault - http://serverfault.com/

Comment: it is installed, get sql server management studio !

Comment: @Tarun: Can you please post a link

Comment: this should do it, just check SQL Server Installation center.. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=56AD557C-03E6-4369-9C1D-E81B33D8026B&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 is installed but you might have to install Client tools for Sql Server 2008 to access the installed instance..